# Clicking on a link blinks/flashes

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

[image]

```
<div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs" id="exCollapsingNavbar2">
      <%= link_to 'FARDIN KHANJANI', root_path, class: 'navbar-brand logo' %>
</div>
```

As you can see in the gif I added, when I click on any of the nav bar links, it flashes. Any ideas what's causing it and how to fix it? I couldn't really come with a proper description for it to try and google it.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Have you tried anything similar to this?

`.navbar-brand logo a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it must be something related to the anchor tag active css rule, `a.active` rule. You can find out which css rule is actually causing it by inspecting the element.

By using chrome window you can do this. Follow the steps

1) select the desired element in inspector

2) use the `Toggle Element State` Option

3) set the state to `active`

Now you can find out which CSS rule is causing the issue and fix it, whether with custom css or modifying the rule in original code.

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm :)

Comment: Glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 2):

You should try giving `.logo:active, .logo:focus` a `background-color: transparent;` because when you click it, a `background-color` is initiated.